# using connectWith on dynamically created list jquery-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Ok, so I'm new and I'm beating my head against the wall!

First here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddle_me_this/kN272/30/

And the code to boot:

```
var myArr = [];
var myStr = "";
var restoreList = [];


$(document).ready(function () {
    //source file = https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/17T3iZRygAry052J4clYoVnBUz1h_2ZttBY1mDBh7ZEs/od6/public/basic?alt=json-in-script&callback=?

    if (restoreList.length === 0) {

        $(function listPlayers() {

            $.getJSON("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/17T3iZRygAry052J4clYoVnBUz1h_2ZttBY1mDBh7ZEs/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=?",

            function (data) {
                $.each(data.feed.entry, function (i, entry) {
                    myStr = entry.gsx$player.$t;
                    myArr.push(myStr);
                });

                //store default list data
                localStorage.myJSON = JSON.stringify(myArr);

            });
        });

    } else {

        $('#header').html('Data Exists');

    }

});


restoreList = JSON.parse(localStorage.myJSON);
$('#header').html('Offensive Players');
//just using 10 names for now there's over 200 total
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $('#player-list').append('<li class="player"><span class="name">' + restoreList[i] + '</span></li>');
    if (i === restoreList.length - 1) {
        localStorage.clear();
    }
}

$('#player-list').sortable('refresh');

$('#player-list').sortable({
    connectWith: "ul"
});
```

I am unable to take the dynamically created list, pulled from a google doc, to connectWith the corresponding list (in gray).

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if this is what you want or not

http://jsfiddle.net/kN272/31/

`$('#player-list , #player-list2').sortable({
    connectWith: ".connected"
});`

Comment: yes! Absolutely! I'm not sure why I can't get this to work in my own environment. I appreciate the help.